# What kind of graph was github's impact graph?

Tags: visualization

Github used to have a graph called an impact graph.  It feels almost like a Sankey diagram and almost like a stacked area chart.  What is the name of this kind of graph?

[image: Github Impact Graph]

I couldn't find a better stackexchange site on which to post this question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a statistics site ("Cross Validated", http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ); that might be a better choice for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a stream graph. The output seems similar to QlikView's stream graph.